# Any similar quasi Turing complete systems?

Tags: evm

In the literature, are there any remotely similar quasi Turing complete systems like Ethereum (EVM), that "charge" for each step of computation?  Anything that the EVM could learn from?

Answer (score 2):

Gridcoin is as close as it comes right now as far as I know: https://www.gridcoin.us/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.